# Can Xively show a log of text messages from a device?

Tags: xively

Is Xively ONLY capable of showing graphs of values, or sending responses to triggers, etc?  **Is there any way to create a little scrollable message window and see log-type messages as they happen?**

Seems like most of the info on the Xively site is marketing hype and a formal API spec, along with some glossy examples and high prices.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Xively datastreams can store string values. You will need to implement a log viewer yourself, which is quite simple to achieve using JavaScript.